# Instance null when using ThreadStatic attribute for static variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, thread-safety

I have Action Method which calls service function using `System.Threading.Task`.

The service function has a static global variable which I have set attribute `ThreadStatic` to make my function Thread-Safe.

My issue is that sometimes when I run my action method the shared variable `_sharedList` throws null reference exception when accessing it in my `HotelService`.

Here is a sample implementation to replicate the issue:

**Controller Action Method calling HotelService.TestMultiThread**

```
public ActionResult MultiThread()
{
  HotelService svc = new HotelService();
  var resp = new List<TestPnrHeaderResponse>();

  var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(i => Task.Run(() => svc.TestMultiThread(i)));

  var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

  return View(resp);
}
```

**HotelService class**

> **_sharedList is Null in line `_sharedList.listInt.AddRange(GetIntList());`**

```
public class HotelService
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static TestPnrHeaderResponse _sharedList;

    private void LoadCache()
    {
        _sharedList = new TestPnrHeaderResponse();
        _sharedList.PnrLegs = new List<PnrLegVM>();
        _sharedList.listInt = new List<int>();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            _sharedList.listInt.AddRange(GetIntList());
        });
    }

    private IEnumerable<int> GetIntList()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, 5);
    }
    public TestPnrHeaderResponse TestMultiThread(int count)
    {
        LoadCache();

        if (count % 2 == 0)
        {
            _sharedList.PnrLegs.Add(new PnrLegVM
            {
                ApplicationType = count.ToString(),
                PKCity = count,
                PKNationality = 1,
                PKPnrHeader = 1,
                PKPnrLeg = 1
            });
        }
        else
        {
            _sharedList.PnrLegs.Add(new PnrLegVM
            {
                ApplicationType = count.ToString(),
                PKCity = count,
                PKNationality = 99,
                PKPnrHeader = 99,
                PKPnrLeg = 99
            });

        }
        return _sharedList;
    }
}
```

**Shared Variable class**

```
public class TestPnrHeaderResponse
{
   public List<PnrLegVM> PnrLegs { get; set; }
   public List<int> listInt { get; set; }
}
public class PnrLegVM
{
   public int PKPnrLeg{get;set;}

   public int PKPnrHeader{get;set;}      
   public string ApplicationType{get;set;}
   public int PKNationality {get;set;}
}
```

Please help to find solution for this. Also, is there a better way to make the function Thread-safe as it uses many shared variables in actual implementation.

Comment: Tasks aren't threads. They are jobs that run on a reusable threadpool thread. That means that storing anything in ThreadStatic storage almost guarantees you'll lose it. There's no guarantee that the same thread will be reused by any of your tasks

Comment: Your code is over-complicated too. There's no reason to use cold tasks or place them in arrays. They aren't threads. If you wanted to perform 5 calls in the background, just use 5 `Task.Run` calls and await for the results with `await Task.WhenAll(...);`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I understand Tasks aren't threads. I am trying to find a better solution to `ThreadStatic` as I asked in question aswell.

Comment: And yet, you are treating them this way, by creating cold tasks, storing them in arrays, calling `.Start`, using `ThreadStatic` which has no meaning when you don't know what thread you are running on. Why do you want a `ThreadStatic` anyway? What are you trying to do? It won't make the list thread-safe, if that's what you intended.

Comment: If you try to lazily initialize the list, use `Lazy<T>`. To generate 5 running tasks, use `var tasks=Enumerable.Range(0,5).Select(int i=>Task.Run(()=>svc.TestMultiThread(i));var results=await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`. Or you can use PLINQ - just use `AsParallel()` in a query.

Comment: My actual implementation is very complicated. I will try implementing `Task.WhenAll() `as you mentioned. In actual implementaion I have a service layer like here `HotelService`. I need to call this `HotelService` functions using Tasks. But my issue is that `HotelService` uses global variables which makes my function not thread-safe

Comment: Then simplify it. Just this snippet has several smells. As for global variables, use `Lazy<T>` and/or one of the concurrent collections, like ConcurrentDictionary

Comment: My main issue is private global variables in `HotelService` functions which throw errors when I make calls using Task

Comment: Yes, I understand. Don't. Did you check `Lazy<T>` ?

Comment: Not much aware about it. For ConcurrentDictionary wil have to change my variable references at 100s of places. To avoid that was trying out ThreadStatic. I will use concurrentDictionary if no option other than that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145125/discussion-between-user3250-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the suggestions above and [here](http://reedcopsey.com/2011/01/16/concurrentdictionarytkeytvalue-used-with-lazyt/) I have settled for below implementation by using `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, Lazy<TValue>>`:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult MultiThread()
{
 HotelService svc = new HotelService();
 var resp = new List<TestPnrHeaderResponse>();
 var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(i => Task.Run(() => svc.TestMultiThread(i)));
 var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
 return View(resp);
}
```

**Hotel Service class**

```
public class HotelService
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<int, Lazy<TestPnrHeaderResponse>> _sharedList
        = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Lazy<TestPnrHeaderResponse>>();

    private TestPnrHeaderResponse LoadGetCache(int count)
    {
        var resp = new Lazy<TestPnrHeaderResponse>();
        resp.Value.PnrLegs = new List<PnrLegVM>();
        resp.Value.listInt = new List<int>();
        List<int> listInt = resp.Value.listInt;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            listInt.AddRange(GetIntList());
        });

        return resp.Value;
    }

    private IEnumerable<int> GetIntList()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, 5);
    }
    public TestPnrHeaderResponse TestMultiThread(int count)
    {
        var resp = new TestPnrHeaderResponse();
        resp = _sharedList.GetOrAddLazy(count,(k)=> LoadGetCache(k));

        if (resp == null)
        {
            LoadGetCache(count);
        }
        if (resp != null)
        {
            if (count % 2 == 0)
            {
                resp.PnrLegs.Add(new PnrLegVM
                {
                    ApplicationType = count.ToString(),
                    PKCity = count,
                    PKNationality = 1,
                    PKPnrHeader = 1,
                    PKPnrLeg = 1
                });
                resp.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted;
            }
            else
            {
                resp.PnrLegs.Add(new PnrLegVM
                {
                    ApplicationType = count.ToString(),
                    PKCity = count,
                    PKNationality = 99,
                    PKPnrHeader = 99,
                    PKPnrLeg = 99
                });
                resp.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Redirect;
            }
        }

        return resp;
    }
}
```

**Extension method from answer [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2040/138899)**

```
public static V GetOrAddLazy<T, V>(this System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<T, Lazy<V>> dictionary, T key, Func<T, V> valueFactory)
{
      var lazy = dictionary.GetOrAdd(key, new Lazy<V>(() => valueFactory(key), LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication));
      return lazy.Value;
}
```

Hope it helps someone facing kind of same issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> _sharedList is Null in line _sharedList.listInt.AddRange(GetIntList());

It's surprising that it's not *always* `null` at that point. You are executing that code in an entirely new thread, where you have *not* called `LoadCache()` and thus have not initialized the field. If you accidentally wind up getting a non-`null` value, that's only because you are getting executed in a thread pool thread where, for *some other* value of the `count` parameter, the `LoadCache()` method was called. Of course, in that case, while the value is non-`null`, it's not the list you think it is.

It is not clear to me why you are delegating that work to yet another thread, especially when you are trying to tie the `_sharedList` variable to just a single thread. It's also not clear to me why you are modifying the list without any sort of synchronization, even though you obviously expect that object to be the one in use in two different, unsynchronized threads.

But ignoring those issues for the moment, you *could* address the `null` issue by capturing the value in a local variable and using that in the anonymous method:

```
private void LoadCache()
{
    _sharedList = new TestPnrHeaderResponse();
    _sharedList.PnrLegs = new List<PnrLegVM>();
    _sharedList.listInt = new List<int>();

    List<int> listInt = _sharedList.listInt;

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        listInt.AddRange(GetIntList());
    });
}
```

The local `listInt` variable will get the reference to the list referenced by your `_sharedList` object, and then that variable is captured in the anonymous method, so that it's assured of being the list you really want to use in that task.

In the code you posted, the `TestMultiThread()` method does not actually use `_sharedList.listInt`, and so in theory there's no conflict. But there's not enough context in your question to know whether that field is used elsewhere at some other time. Frankly, it's not even clear why `_sharedList` is a `static` field in the first place. All of the code you posted could have been written by making the variable a local variable, used only the methods shown.

But, if you really need the code to work as you've shown, the above will address the `null` value you are asking about.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. In my actual implementation `_sharedList` is a global private **non-static** variable used at many many places in my HotelService functions. I wanted to make my HotelService functions to make it thread-safe when calling from another service. So, I found this method to use ThreadStatic and trying it out.

Comment: `_sharedList.listInt` here listInt in my actual code is very complex object which uses `Task`s to fetch data from DB using EF. Like country list, city list, airport list as class properties. To mimic that code I used `listInt`. Its used at many places in `HotelService` in my code. Basically, my service is a search hotel service which uses initial data set by `LoadCache()` method at start of search.

Comment: @User3250: sorry, I don't know what to do with the extra information in your comments. Fact is, `[ThreadStatic]` is exactly that: for a specific thread. The code you posted intentionally executes code one thread is dependent on, in a different thread, where the value of that field is guaranteed to be difference (_because_ you used `[ThreadStatic]`). Either the code you posted is representative of what you're actually doing, in which case my answer here addresses your question, or it's not, in which case you need to change the code example so that it does.

Comment: Yes your answer does address my question here. Do you have any good reads on `ConcurrentDictionary` or other Concurrency method usages?

Comment: @User3250: concurrency and thread-safety is a very broad topic. I'm afraid I don't know of any single resource that would do it. I will say, `[ThreadStatic]` is not a magic bullet, and comes with its own pitfalls. While there are many strategies for safe concurrency, IMHO the two best are immutable data structures (may not be possible in your case), and dedicating data structures to a specific thread (could be possible in your case, but does not require the use of `[ThreadStatic]`). In other words, either make it so that the data doesn't change, or make it so if it does, only one thread cares